# Method not executing when accessing from a different class

Tags: java, function

Recently, I built a a connect four program on Java. However, I built it procedurally, so now I am trying to refactor my code to ensure that it is Object Oriented.

So far, I have managed to split the initial program into two different classes, which are as follows:

**ConnectFour.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ConnectFour {

private BufferedReader input;


public ConnectFour() {

    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    playGame();
}



private String getUserInput(){
    String toReturn = null;
    try{            
        toReturn = input.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    return toReturn;
}

public void playGame() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Connect 4");
    System.out.println("There are 2 players red and yellow");
    System.out.println("Player 1 is Red, Player 2 is Yellow");
    System.out.println("To play the game type in the number of the column you want to drop you counter in");
    System.out.println("A player wins by connecting 4 counters in a row - vertically, horizontally or diagonally");
    System.out.println("");

    Board board = new Board();
    board.printBoard();

    boolean win = false;
    while(!win){

        // player 1
        String userInput = getUserInput();
        int move = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        Board counter = new Board();
        counter.placeCounter('r', move);

        Board bop = new Board();
        char[][] boardx = bop.getBoard();


        boolean hasWon = false;
        int count = 0;
        // check horizontal
        for(int i=0; i<boardx.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<boardx[i].length; j++){
                if(boardx[i][j] == 'r'){
                    count = count + 1;
                    if(count >= 4){
                        hasWon = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        // check vertical 
        count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<boardx[0].length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<boardx.length; j++){
                if(boardx[j][i] == 'r'){
                    count = count + 1;
                    if(count >= 4){
                        hasWon = true;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        board.printBoard();
        if(hasWon){
            win = true;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("R, You Have Won!!!");
        }
        else{
            //player 2
            userInput = getUserInput();
            move = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            counter.placeCounter('y', move);;
            hasWon = false;
            count = 0;
            // check horizontal
            for(int i=0; i<boardx.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<boardx[i].length; j++){
                    if(boardx[i][j] == 'y'){
                        count = count + 1;
                        if(count >= 4){
                            hasWon = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
            // check vertical 
            count = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<boardx[0].length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<boardx.length; j++){
                    if(boardx[j][i] == 'y'){
                        count = count + 1;
                        if(count >= 4){
                            hasWon = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
            board.printBoard();
            if(hasWon){
                win = true;
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Y, You Have Won!!!");
            }
        }

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ConnectFour();
}

}
```

**Board.java**

```
public class Board {

private char [][] board;

public Board() {
    board = new char[6][7];

}

public char[][] getBoard() {
    return this.board;
}

public void placeCounter(char player, int position){
    boolean placed = false;


    if(player == 'r'){
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'r' && board[i - 1][position] != 'y') {
                if(board[i][position] == 'y'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'r'){
                    board[i][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (player == 'y') {
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if (!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'r' && board[i - 1][position] != 'y'){
                if(board[i][position] == 'r'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'y'){
                    board[i][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void printBoard(){

    for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<board[0].length;j++){
            if(board[i][j] == 0)
                System.out.print(".  ");
            else
                System.out.print(board[i][j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("*  *  *  *  *  *  *");
    System.out.println("0  1  2  3  4  5  6");
}

}
```

When I run the program, the board displays fine. However, when i try to place a counter by selecting the row number, no counter is added to the board.

Could somebody explain to me why this is happening? I have checked my code many times and from what I can see, everything is properly encapsulated and called correctly.

Appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you keep creating new Boards() in the same loop and that wipes out the old one.  Why do you have counter as a board and bop as a board?  And which one do you print?

```java
    // player 1
        String userInput = getUserInput();
        int move = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        Board counter = new Board();
        counter.placeCounter('r', move);

        Board bop = new Board();
        char[][] boardx = bop.getBoard();
```

Edited:

Do not use more than one instance of the Board class. Do the following.  Place these two statements above your while statement as shown below.

```java
      counter = new Board();
      counter.printBoard();
      while (!win) {
```

Then remove every other instance of your board and replace all references to those boards with counter.  You only need one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply WJS. I had to do two because if i remove bop then icannot use the board variable

Comment: Check the edited answer.  You only need a single instance of board.